# Specify image by name

Tags: python

[image]

I made a specific image for the selected object，Now there are three planes in the scene，Plane.1, Plane.2, Plane.3 respectively,If there are three images with the same name in this folder，How to add them to the corresponding plane automatically?How to write such a script with the if else statement?

Comment: What do you need this for? Why would you create the planes manually, if you want it to be automatic? Doesn't it make sense to create the planes automatically as well in this situation? Could you provide some more context?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [This](https://i.imgur.com/QiZXPfd.png) would probably work. Both: as a possible solution and as a good explanation, why one should not post code as an image.